# Company name in SoP

Tags: masters, computer-science, statement-of-purpose

I am applying for an MS in CS in USA.
Is it fine to mention the name of a company in the SOP?
Eg. I want to work on exciting problems like the xxx Project in xxx company or yyy Project in yyy company.

Comment: Are you talking about the companies you want to work for post-MS? Or are you looking at programs where they place grad students in industry positions and they conduct part of their MS research there?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I would recommend against it. It doesn't seem to really add anything unless you know the university is involved in research with those companies.

Instead, I'd focus on the field and subfield that you want to study. Having a problem in hand when you apply is probably less important than it might be elsewhere and there is more to learn in grad school than just how to solve some particular problem.

OTOH, I don't think it would hurt much. And "*exciting* problems" sounds a bit trite. But "being intrigued by" certain problems is probably a good thing, not just for the application.